# Second Dropdownlist is not filtering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I am making an application , that allows the user to select a service from a list of services and an employee from a list of employees. When a user selects a service , the dropdownlist for the employees must automatically filter to show the employees that can perform that service or have that skill. For example if a customer selects a haircut , only employees whose skill is a haircut must filter into the dropdown list. I will show you my code , note : i do not want to create a relationship between service and employee.

The first dropdownlist is populating but not the second dropdownlist. Please view my code below

```
    public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public string ServiceID { get; set;}
    public string ServiceName { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public double Price { get; set;}
 }


 public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public string EmpID { get; set;}
    public string EmpName { get; set;}
    public string Skills { get; set;}

}

 public class Cascade
{
    [Key]
    public int cKey { get; set;}
    public string ServiceRequried { get; set;}
    public string EmployeeRequired { get; set;}


}

 public ActionResult Index3()
    {
        List<Service> ServiceList = db.Services.ToList();
        ViewBag.ServiceList = new SelectList(ServiceList, "ServiceID", "ServiceName");
        return View();

    }
    public JsonResult GetEmpList2(string ServiceRequired)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Employee> EmpList = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Skills == ServiceRequired).ToList();
        return Json(EmpList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

 @model SkillScheduling2.Models.Cascade

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index3";
 }

 <h2>Index3</h2>

 <br /><br />

<div class="form-group">
    @if (ViewBag.ServiceList != null)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceRequried, ViewBag.ServiceList as SelectList, "--Select Service--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    }
</div>



 <div class="form-group">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeRequired, new SelectList(" "), "--Select Employee--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ServiceRequired").change(function () {
        $.get("/Home/GetEmpList2", { ServiceRequired: $("#ServiceRequired").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#EmployeeRequired").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#EmployeeRequired").append("<option value='" + row.EmpID + "'>" + row.EmpName + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, what is the error you are getting? can you log the value of `data` in JavaScript and tell me what you get. I hope that the last div for the `EmployeeRequired` is a typo error. if you are not getting to the controller then consider using `url: "@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))/Home/GetEmpList2"`

Comment: I have figured out the problem , if i hard code values into the drop down list for Service Required ,the filter works. But if i try to pull values from the Service Table , the filter does not work. Any ideas on how to solve this

Comment: Can you please show me where to add console.log(data) , thank you

Comment: here `$.get("/Home/GetEmpList2", { ServiceRequired: $("#ServiceRequired").val() }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#EmployeeRequired").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#EmployeeRequired").append("<option value='" + row.EmpID + "'>" + row.EmpName + "</option>")
            });
        });`

Comment: []length: 0__proto__: Array(0) , this is what the console is showing

Comment: So the problem is from your controller. Are you sure you have data in the db that matches the condition `List<Employee> EmpList = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Skills == ServiceRequired).ToList();`

Comment: According to SQL Management Studio :1) Employee ID : 123A , EmployeeName : Bob, Skills : Haircut 2) Employee ID : 123B , EmployeeName : Same, Skills : Haircut 3) Employee ID : 123C , EmployeeName : James, Skills : Shave.  Service Table 1) ServiceID : 456A , ServiceName:Haircut , Price:50 2) ServiceID : 456B , ServiceName:Shave , Price:30

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceRequired,
    new List<SelectListItem>
    {
new SelectListItem {Text="--Select Country--" },
new SelectListItem {Text="Shave" },
new SelectListItem {Text="Massage" },
new SelectListItem {Text="Haircut" }
    } ,new {@class ="Select Item"})

Comment: If i hard code values it works , but if i populate it with values from Service table it does not work, it makes no sense , because the values i hard code is also in the db

Comment: can you put a break point in your `GetEmpList2` method and see what `EmpList` is from there?

Comment: You mentioned that the code worked for you , what data did you seed

Comment: Did you make any changes to my code for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This is where I think you need to make changes base on the data in your db.

Your db has `ServiceName` and not the `ServiceId`, so change this line **new SelectList(ServiceList, "ServiceID", "ServiceName");** to **new SelectList(ServiceList, "ServiceName", "ServiceName");**

```
public ActionResult Index3()
{
    List<Service> ServiceList = db.Services.ToList();
    ViewBag.ServiceList = new SelectList(ServiceList, "ServiceName", "ServiceName");
    return View();

}
```